# Batch printing for print jobs containing multiple documents with different print settings

Tags: windows, automation, printing

#### Background

I'm currently using [Batch & Print Pro](http://www.traction-software.co.uk/batchprint/). Here's how we're using it:

1. We've setup a set of print settings, e.g. settings for printing a document on premium paper stock with an embossed logo with stapling, settings for printing 'copy' versions of documents on standard paper stock with no stapling, etc.
2. We generate a set of PDFs to be printed as a single 'job'<sup>1</sup>.
3. We create a 'job' file for Batch & Print Pro that indicates which print setting to apply and which document (PDF file) to print.
4. We run a GUI version of Batch & Print Pro using the job file created in step [3].

One problem is that because the documents are printed as separate jobs, we have to manually (via email) ask everyone with access to the relevant printer to not use the printer for the duration of the printing. Ideally, this would be handled by the batch printing software (or some other software, e.g. a print server program, service, or server computer).

One reason why we 'interleave' documents with different print settings is that doing so greatly reduces the need to collate documents and pages after printing, e.g. for documents that will be mailed, all documents and pages that will be stuffed into the same envelope should be printed together.

#### Requirements

- Print PDFs
- Print multiple documents (PDFs), in a specific order
- Support multiple printer settings for specific documents
- Automation, e.g. control via command-line, API, web service

#### Notes

<sup>1</sup> Each document is currently spooled in the queue on the printer as a separate job.